# Not able to send email to a google group via Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, google-groups

I am using Rails Action Mailers to send mails. I am successfully able to send emails to individual id's. I want to send email to a google group so that it mails all the people subscribed to that group. If I just email the group using my gmail account, all subscribers get the email but not through Action Mailer. Console output looks like it did send but unfortunately subscribers are not getting it.

```
 #<Mail::Message:70252634244300, Multipart: false, Headers: <Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 14:02:04 -0500>, <From: test@gmail.com>, <To: <google-group>@gmail.com>, <Message-ID: <51e052ac70b3f_a2df3fe4f5c35ae0536c4@GM15973.group.on.mail>>, <Subject: Welcome!>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>, <Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable>>
```

Mailer

```
class BlahMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "test@gmail.com"

  def welcome_email
    @mail = "google-group@gmail.com"
    @tweets = Twitter.user_timeline("tweettest").first.text
    mail(to: @mail, subject: 'Welcome!')
  end
```

If I replace `google-group@gmail.com` with an indvidual's id, it works fine.

Comment: can you please copy and paste some of the mailer logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The google group belongs to the organization whereas I was trying to send email from a regular gmail account. Changed the group settings to allow external accounts to post to it and it worked.